# Are there any models that do worse on standardized datasets?

Tags: regression, classification, normalization, data-preprocessing

#### Background

I am currently an undergraduate student beginning to explore the field of data science. Recently, our professor introduced us to the concept of standardizing a dataset.

My professor mentioned that normalizing/standardizing a dataset is performed in order to address the problem of features having different ranges/scales. He also mentioned that certain models are extremely sensitive to features having different scales (e.g. KNN) while other models simply don't care at all (e.g. decision trees).

#### Question

**My question today is, do any classification/regression models exist such that they actually perform worse on a standardized dataset than the original dataset itself?**

The reason I ask this question is to decide whether or not to always normalize incoming data.

If the answer to my question is yes, then I will have to be smart about when to normalize, and when not to.

If the answer to my question is no, then I will just simply always normalize incoming data.